# Why does parts of my rigged model fall off while moving it?

Tags: animation, rigging

[image]
[image]

Whenever I move the model these parts fall off, the model is one connected piece and if I disconnect it it only splits into the helmet and torso. I have tried re-rigging the model but it still doesn't work

Comment: Are the loose parts separate objects or parts of the same mesh? 
If they are parts of the same mesh, they are probably not assigned weights properly.
If they are separate objects they are probably not parented to the armature.
It's hard to tell without more info or the Blend file.

Comment: They are the same mesh and I don't know how they are not assigned properly, can you explain how that works and how I can fix it?

Comment: It's a basic procedure when rigging, you have to assign weights to the vertices (weights = how much each bone affects a given vertex). Search for armature weight painting, or look for a comprehensive rigging tutorial, there are many on YouTube.

Comment: Wow that worked, thanks so much, finally someone can help me on the internet